# How to dynamically set value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script below where I dynamically need to replace three values and I can't get it to work.

The values can be find as a string in an element on the page.

I tried to add this at the end of the script for each value:

```
ccs_cc_args.push(['MPN', $(".productboxArticlenumber").text()]);
```

This shows the correct value in console and it gives me something like this:

```
[["MFR_NAME", "Apple"], ["MPN", "MLH82N/A"], ["CPN", "244992"]]
```

But the script itself is not updated - and it wont do what it is supposed to do.

How do I make the script dynamically update from the target element's string?

HTML:

```
<div class="productboxArticlenumber">MLH82N/A</div>
```

Script:

```
  var ccs_cc_args = ccs_cc_args || [];
  ccs_cc_args.push(['cpn', 'CPN']);         ///Dynamically replace the CPN text
  ccs_cc_args.push(['mf', 'MFR_NAME']);     //Dynamically replace the MFR_NAME text
  ccs_cc_args.push(['pn', 'MPN']);          //Dynamically replace the MPN text
  ccs_cc_args.push(['lang', 'nl']);
  ccs_cc_args.push(['market', 'NL']);

  (function () {
     var o = ccs_cc_args; o.push(['_SKey', '3a535060']); o.push(['_ZoneId', '6cddbf26bb']); 
     var sc = document.createElement('script'); sc.type = 'text/javascript'; sc.async = true;
     sc.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.cnetcontent.com/jsc/h.js';
     var n = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; n.parentNode.insertBefore(sc, n);
   })();

   ccs_cc_args.push(['MPN', $(".productboxArticlenumber").text()]);  //added part to push the value dynamic
```

Comment: Do you mean setting those variables in place of say `'CPN'` and others is not working??

Comment: Yes- its supposed to add some html in the page, but the target element is empty. If i set the the values manually in the script for one product page it works, but just for that page then of course. When I try to dynamically add the value as shown above, it wont work.

Comment: Have you put `ccs_cc_args.push(['MPN', $(".productboxArticlenumber").text()]);` inside [document.ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)??

Comment: Hi again. Yes i tried that too - think i tried all ways to set different location of the parts of the script.

Comment: Can you show how did you try that exactly ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. so the solution was simple - I replaced the wrong value.

```
ccs_cc_args.push(['MPN', $(".productboxArticlenumber").text()]);
```

Should have been

```
ccs_cc_args.push(['pn', $(".productboxArticlenumber").text()]);
```